# Microsoft Access 2007 - How to Change Path to Database

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been asked to make some changes to an Access database used by a local company.  The database is on a server and is in Access 2003 format (mdb).  The company is using Access 2007.  The previous programmer is no longer available and there is very little documentation.  Now, I copied the database (delta.mdb) and the back-end database (delta_be.mdb) to my computer at home so I can work on it.  When I run the database the following error message appears:
"//deltamain/orderprogram/delta_be.mdb" is not a valid path.  I then went into VBA and searched for references to "delta_be.mdb" so I could change the path.  But I could not find any references.
Question 1 - Can someone tell me where the path to the back-end database is stored?  Perhaps it's a property of the database? I can't find it anywhere.
Question 2- Is there a way to print a list of the names of all the objects in the database.  I don't want to analyze the objects, just print the names.
Thank you!

Comment: Open Linked Table Manager (I believe under Database Tools in 2007, External Data in 2010/13/16), select all tables and hit OK to browse for backend file on your computer.

Comment: Thank you, Parfait.  The Linked Table Manager worked, and I am now able to work with the database.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 - Can someone tell me where the path to the back-end database is stored? Perhaps it's a property of the database? I can't find it anywhere.

Answer 1 : eexternal links or Path are stored in the **MsysObjects** system table in the database.

Below sql will give all the linked table name and Connect(link to backend)

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name, MsysObjects.Connect
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (((MsysObjects.Connect) Is Not Null));
```

Question 2- Is there a way to print a list of the names of all the objects in the database.

Answer 2: Below sql will give you all the user and system object on the Database.

```
SELECT * FROM MsysObjects
```